# How would I select a div ID with a specific class and then move that class to the next ID with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have this code:

```
<div class="m-item m-active">
</div>

<div class="m-item">
</div>

<div class="m-item">
</div>
```

What I want to do is when I click a button, jquery finds the div with the class of "m-item" that has the class of "m-active", removes the "m-active" class from that div and moves it to the next "m-item" div.

So after clicking the button, the code should look like this (where m-active is on the second div):

```
<div class="m-item">
</div>

<div class="m-item m-active">
</div>

<div class="m-item">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate ID's in the same HTML document - they need to be unique

Comment: Yes, I actually just realized that and was just about to fix it.

Comment: What should happen when the last div has the class and you click the button? Nothing, or should the first div then get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.m-active').removeClass('m-active').next('.m-item').addClass('m-active');
```

Further reading:

[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed.  And thanks for the reading info.  How would I make it so that after the last div, nothing happens when the button is clicked?

Comment: I believe (I may be corrected here) that the above line will do nothing if there is no immediately following sibling div that has the class m-item (i.e. the behaviour you described).

Answer (score 2):

This answer handles wrapping around to the first element once the end is reached. It will also work if none of the elements are active.

When the button is clicked, find the active element, then use the jQuery [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function to find the next `.m-item`. If that item isn't found (`next.length === 0`), then get the first `.m-item`. Finally toggle the `m-active` class:

```
$('#get-next').on('click', function() {
    var active = $('.m-active');
    var next = active.next('.m-item');
    if(next.length === 0) {
         next = $('.m-item').eq(0);   
    }

    active.removeClass('m-active');
    next.addClass('m-active');    
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4mPK/)**